# Left Outer Join is not giving any result

Tags: mysql, database, plsql

I want to join the tables which would have all values from the table Portal_Order alongwith other matching values from other tables.
LEft outer Join returns no values

Query :

```
With Max_Date As (Select Max(Change_Date) Change_Date, Ocoe_Job_Id 
From Ocoe_Job_Status Where Ocoe_Job_Id In 
(Select Ocoe_Job_Id From Portal_Order Where To_Char(Created_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
Between ( Select To_Char(Sysdate-1000,'YYYY-MM-DD') From Dual) 
And ( Select To_Char(Sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') From Dual)  ) 
Group By Ocoe_Job_Id) 

Select Order_Id, Order_Name, Order_Desc, B.Description As Order_Status, C.Ocoe_Job_Id, C.Comments 
As Communication_Id , Communication_Name, Created_By, Count(*) Over () As Total_Record_Count, Row_Number()
Over ( Order By Order_Id ) Row_Number 
From  Max_Date D,
Ocoeowner.Portal_Order A
Left Outer Join Ocoeowner.Ocoe_Job_Status C On C.Ocoe_Job_Id =A.Ocoe_Job_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ocoeowner.Portal_Order_Status_Code_Lk B on A.Order_Status = B.Status_Code
 Where To_Char(Created_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
Between ( Select To_Char(Sysdate-1000,'YYYY-MM-DD') From Dual) And ( Select To_Char(Sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') From Dual)  
And C.Ocoe_Job_Id = D.Ocoe_Job_Id And D.Change_Date = C.Change_Date AND communication_name='ptuletters';
```

Comment: As you are using Dual table (and plsql) that suggests you are using Oracle rather than MySQL

Comment: MySQL does NOT support `with name as ...` either, so it appears to be an incorrect tag

Answer (score 0):

The predicate condition needs to be in the `On` clause for the join, not in the where clause. The way Outer joins work, is after the join conditions are analyzed, all the rows from the "outer side" that do not match the inner side are added back in.... But this all happens before the where clause is processed. So if the where clause predicate filters on an attribute from the outer side of an outer join, all those rows will be removed again... (They are all null). Put the predicate in the join condition instead

```
And C.Ocoe_Job_Id = D.Ocoe_Job_Id And D.Change_Date = C.Change_Date
```

has to be moved, and may be too `AND communication_name='ptuletters'`, depending of the source table

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WITH Max_Date AS
  (SELECT MAX(Change_Date) Change_Date,
    Ocoe_Job_Id
  FROM Ocoe_Job_Status
  WHERE Ocoe_Job_Id IN
    (SELECT Ocoe_Job_Id
    FROM Portal_Order
    WHERE TO_CHAR(Created_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN
      ( SELECT TO_CHAR(Sysdate-1000,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Dual
      )
    AND ( SELECT TO_CHAR(Sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Dual)
    )
  GROUP BY Ocoe_Job_Id
  )

SELECT Order_Id,
  Order_Name,
  Order_Desc,
  B.Description AS Order_Status,
  C.Ocoe_Job_Id,
  C.Comments AS Communication_Id ,
  Communication_Name,
  Created_By,
  COUNT(*) Over () AS Total_Record_Count,
  Row_Number() Over ( Order By Order_Id ) Row_Number
FROM 
 Ocoeowner.Portal_Order A LEFT OUTER JOIN Ocoeowner.Ocoe_Job_Status C ON
  A.Ocoe_Job_Id=C.Ocoe_Job_Id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Ocoeowner.Portal_Order_Status_Code_Lk B ON
  A.Order_Status = B.Status_Code
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Max_Date D ON
  C.Ocoe_Job_Id     = D.Ocoe_Job_Id
  AND C.Change_Date     = D.Change_Date
WHERE 
 TO_CHAR(Created_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN
  ( SELECT TO_CHAR(Sysdate-1000,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Dual
  )
 AND ( SELECT TO_CHAR(Sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM Dual)
AND NVL(communication_name, 'ptuletters')='ptuletters';
```